# Save scroll-position after submit

Tags: javascript, php

i need some help :) I Have a programmed php site (not programmed by me) and want to save the scroll positon after submit ("eintragen").

Hope you can help me.
Here is the code:

```html
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box table-responsive">
                    <h2>Offene Turnierspiele (noch <?=countOffeneSpieleVonTurniereID($turniere_id)?> Spiele)</h2>     
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr bgcolor="#E8E8E8">
                            <td width="5%" align="center"><b>ID</b></td>
                            <td width="5%" align="center"><b>Spielort</b></td>
                            <td width="5%" align="center"><b>Zeit</b></td>
                            <td width="5%" align="center"><b>Gruppe</b></td>
                            <td width="5%" align="center"><b>Spieltag</b></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="right"><b>Heim</b></td>
                            <td width="5%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="5%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left"><b>Gast</b></td>
                            <td width="15%" align="center"><b>Info</b></td>
                            <td width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
<?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT spiele_id, turnierspiele_id, spielort, gruppe, spieltag, team_heim, team_gast, tore_heim, tore_gast, spielinfo, datum FROM b_spiele WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' ORDER BY turnierspiele_id ASC");
                        while($db = $query->fetch_object()):
?>
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                            <tr>
                             <td align="center"><?=$db->turnierspiele_id?></td>
                                <td align="center"><?=$db->spielort?></td>
                                <td align="center">
<?php
         if(isset($db->datum)):
          echo date("H:i", $db->datum)." Uhr";
         endif;
?>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center"><?=$db->gruppe?></td>
                                <td align="center">
<?php
         if(getTurniermodusIDVonTurniereID($turniere_id) == 1):
          echo $db->spieltag;
         else:
          echo getShortTurnierrundenname(getTurnierrundenteilnehmerVonTurniereID($turniere_id,$db->spieltag));
         endif;
?>
        </td>
                                <td align="right"><?=getTurnierteamVonTurnierteamID($turniere_id,$db->team_heim)?></td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="number" name="tore_heim" class="form-control" value="<?=$db->tore_heim?>" required /></td>
                                <td align="center"><input type="number" name="tore_gast" class="form-control" value="<?=$db->tore_gast?>" required /></td>
                                <td align="left"><?=getTurnierteamVonTurnierteamID($turniere_id,$db->team_gast)?></td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <select name="spielinfo" size="1" class="form-control">
<?php
          if($db->spielinfo == 0 || $db->spielinfo == 1):
           echo "<option value='1' selected='selected'>Reguläre Spielzeit</option>";
           echo "<option value='2'>nach Verlängerung</option>";
           echo "<option value='3'>nach Elfmeterschießen</option>";
          elseif($db->spielinfo == 2):
           echo "<option value='1'>Reguläre Spielzeit</option>";
           echo "<option value='2' selected='selected'>nach Verlängerung</option>";
           echo "<option value='3'>nach Elfmeterschießen</option>";
          elseif($db->spielinfo == 3):
           echo "<option value='1'>Reguläre Spielzeit</option>";
           echo "<option value='2'>nach Verlängerung</option>";
           echo "<option value='3' selected='selected'>nach Elfmeterschießen</option>";
          endif;
?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
<?php
         if(isset($db->team_heim) && isset($db->team_gast)):
?>
                                     <input type="hidden" name="spiele_id" value="<?=$db->spiele_id?>" />
                                     <button type="submit" name="submit_turnierwertung" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Eintragen</button>
<?php
         endif;
?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
<?php     
                        endwhile;
?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php 
   require_once "../../templates/footer.php";
  endif;
 elseif($action == "turnierauswertung"):
  $turniere_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["turnier"]);
  
  $query_turnier = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM b_turniere WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id'");
  $db_turnier = $query_turnier->fetch_object();
   $turnierteilnehmer = $db_turnier->turniergruppen * 2;
   $turnierspielzeit = $db_turnier->turnierspielzeit + 10;
 
  if(countOffeneSpieleVonTurniereID($turniere_id) == 0):
   mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turniere SET beendet = '1' WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id'");
   mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turnierteams SET beendet = '1' WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id'");
   mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO b_turniere (turniername, turniermodus, turnierteilnehmer, turnierfelder, turnierspielzeit, turnierstart, turniergruppenphase_id, turnierrunde, gestartet) VALUES ('$db_turnier->turniername', '2', '$turnierteilnehmer', '$db_turnier->turnierfelder', '$turnierspielzeit', '$time', '$turniere_id', '1', '1')");
   
   $turniere_id_neu = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
   
   ErstelleBracketVonTurniereID($turniere_id_neu);
   
   for($gruppe = 1; $gruppe <= $db_turnier->turniergruppen; $gruppe++):
    $i = 1;
    foreach(getTurniergruppentabelleVonWettbewerbeID($turniere_id,$gruppe) AS $array_wert => $key):
     mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO b_turniertabelle (turniere_id, team_id, gruppe, platzierung) VALUES ('$turniere_id', '".$key["teamid"]."', '$gruppe', '$i')");
    
    $i++;
    endforeach;
   endfor;
   
   $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT team_id FROM b_turniertabelle WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND platzierung = '1' ORDER BY gruppe ASC");
   while($db = $query->fetch_object()):
    $arGruppen1[] = $db->team_id;
    
    mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO b_turnierteams (turniere_id, team_id, team, status) VALUES ('$turniere_id_neu', '$db->team_id', '".getTurnierteamVonTurnierteamID($turniere_id,$db->team_id)."', '2')");
   endwhile;
   
   $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT team_id FROM b_turniertabelle WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND platzierung = '2' ORDER BY gruppe DESC");
   while($db = $query->fetch_object()):
    $arGruppen2[] = $db->team_id;
    
    mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO b_turnierteams (turniere_id, team_id, team, status) VALUES ('$turniere_id_neu', '$db->team_id', '".getTurnierteamVonTurnierteamID($turniere_id,$db->team_id)."', '2')");
   endwhile;
   
   $spielnr = 0;
   $tvnr = 0;   
   
   $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM b_spiele WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id_neu' AND spieltag = '1' ORDER BY spiele_id ASC");
   while($db = $query->fetch_object()):
    $tvnr++;
    $spielort = "TV ".$tvnr;
    
    if($spielnr < $db_turnier->turnierfelder):
     $datum = $time;
    else:
     if($spielnr % $db_turnier->turnierfelder == 0):
      $datum += (($db_turnier->turnierspielzeit + 10) * 60);
     endif;
    endif;
    
    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_spiele SET team_heim = '".$arGruppen1[$spielnr]."', team_gast = '".$arGruppen2[$spielnr]."', spielort = '$spielort', datum = '$datum' WHERE spiele_id = '$db->spiele_id'");

    $spielnr++;
    
    if($tvnr == $db_turnier->turnierfelder):
     $tvnr = 0;
    endif;
   endwhile;
  endif;
  
  header("Location: index.php");
 elseif($action == "turnierauslosung"):
  $turniere_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET["turnier"]);
  
  $query_turnier = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM b_turniere WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id'");
  $db_turnier = $query_turnier->fetch_object();
  
  if(countOffeneRundenspieleVonTurniereID($turniere_id,getTurnierrundeVonTurniereID($turniere_id)) == 0):
   $runde_akt  = getTurnierrundeVonTurniereID($turniere_id);
   $runde_neu  = $runde_akt + 1;
   $teilnehmer_aktuell = getTurnierrundenteilnehmerVonTurniereID($turniere_id,$runde_akt);
  
   if(getTurnierrundenteilnehmerVonTurniereID($turniere_id,$runde_neu) >= 2):
    $spielnr = 1;
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM b_spiele WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND spieltag = '$runde_akt' ORDER BY spiele_id ASC");
    while($db = $query->fetch_object()):
     if($spielnr % 2 == 0):
      if($db->tore_heim > $db->tore_gast):
       $teams_gast[] = $db->team_heim;
       
       mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turnierteams SET beendet = '1' WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND team_id = '$db->team_gast'");
      elseif($db->tore_heim < $db->tore_gast):
       $teams_gast[] = $db->team_gast; 
       
       mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turnierteams SET beendet = '1' WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND team_id = '$db->team_heim'");    
      endif;
     else:
      if($db->tore_heim > $db->tore_gast):
       $teams_heim[] = $db->team_heim;
       
       mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turnierteams SET beendet = '1' WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND team_id = '$db->team_gast'");
      elseif($db->tore_heim < $db->tore_gast):
       $teams_heim[] = $db->team_gast;  
       
       mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turnierteams SET beendet = '1' WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND team_id = '$db->team_heim'");   
      endif;
     endif;
     
     $spielnr++;
    endwhile;
    
    $spielnr = 0;
    $spielenr = 1;
    $tvnr = 0;
    
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM b_spiele WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id' AND spieltag = '$runde_neu' ORDER BY spiele_id ASC");
    while($db = $query->fetch_object()):
     $tvnr++;
     $spielort = "TV ".$tvnr;
     
     if($spielnr < $db_turnier->turnierfelder):
      $datum = $time;
     else:
      if($spielnr % $db_turnier->turnierfelder == 0):
       $datum += ($db_turnier->turnierspielzeit * 60);
      endif;
     endif;
     
     mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_spiele SET team_heim = '".$teams_heim[$spielnr]."', team_gast = '".$teams_gast[$spielnr]."', spielort = '$spielort', datum = '$datum' WHERE spiele_id = '$db->spiele_id'");
 
     $spielnr++;
     $spielenr++;
     
     if($tvnr == $db_turnier->turnierfelder):
      $tvnr = 0;
     endif;
    endwhile;
    
    mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE b_turniere SET turnierrunde = turnierrunde + 1 WHERE turniere_id = '$turniere_id'");
   endif;
  endif;
  
  header("Location: index.php");
 endif;
endif;
?>
```

Thank you so much!I have tested some scripts by searching on google and so on. But nothing will help :(

Comment: You should use Ajax and call a separate PHP file so that you are not redirected from the page.

Comment: problem is here that i am not a programmer. Is it possible to get a fixed file/new file for some $?

Comment: You could have a hidden form field where the value of the scroll position is updated with jquery, and save it to the database when the forms submits.

Comment: Same as the other. That's for me spanish :)